# Webpack/webpack-cleanup-plugin: webpack.config.js that only does the cleanup

Tags: webpack

Is it possible to configure a `webpack.config.js` that only does a cleanup (using "webpack-cleanup-plugin"), without having to configure the `entry` or `output` parameters?

Comment: Install [rimraf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rimraf) to add a script command and use it to do the cleanup, something like `"cleanup": "rimraf dist"` and then run `npm run cleanup` every time you want to delete `dist` (or whatever) dir contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you want to run the cleanup plugin but don't want webpack to bundle your files then that's not possible because primary goal of webpack is to bundle your dependencies and taks like cleanup are add-ons**

**There is probably a better way to do this thing but to answer your question**

> without having to **configure** the entry or output parameters?

yes this is possible with Webpack 4 if you don't specify entry or output parameter it will use the default values which is `src/index.js` for entry and `dist` for `output.folder`

**Webpack will throw a error if entry file is not found**
so if you dont specify entry then `src/index.js` must be present in your project

so lets say your folder structure is as following

```
| src
     |index.js
| libs
| build
```

now if you want to clean the `build` directory then you create a configuration like this

```
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin({
      // takes an array so you can specify multiple patterns
      // build/**/* will clean everything inside build but not build directory itself
      cleanOnceBeforeBuildPatterns: [path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'build/**/*')]
    }),
  ]
};
```

notice that now you need to specify the `cleanOnceBeforeBuildPatterns` because by default `clean-webpack-plugin`

> will remove all files inside webpack's output.path directory

and we didn't specify the output.path so it's default value is `dist` more accurate would be `path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'dist')` but we want to cleanup everything inside `build`

you can specify other options like

`cleanOnceBeforeBuildPatterns`, `cleanAfterEveryBuildPatterns` or event if you want to clean up outside of your project then you cant set `dangerouslyAllowCleanPatternsOutsideProject` to `true`
more info [here](https://github.com/johnagan/clean-webpack-plugin)

because running webpack with this configuration will also create the `dist/main.js` bundle so we need to remove that as well so your script may look like this

```
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "webpack --config webpack.config.js && rm -rf ./dist"
  }
```

---

A more simple way to do this is by specifying a simple bash command in your `package.json` file something like

```
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rm -rf ./build/**"
  }
```

and you can run it like `yarn clean` or `npm run clean`